# How to solve this $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How to solve this?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2}$$

My approach is to use Squeeze theorem but no results. Like this

$$0 < \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2} < \frac{n}{n+2} < 1 $$

Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: $\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}$

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice

Comment: @R.V.N. Here $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}$ -> $\frac{1}{\infty + 0}$ -> 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must divide by the highest power of $n$, i.e. by $1$:
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{1+\frac{2}{n}}~\to~\frac{0}{1}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}{\frac{n+2}{\sqrt{n}}}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\infty+\frac{2}{\infty}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\infty+0}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\infty}$$
$$=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$0 \lt \dfrac {\sqrt{n}}{(\sqrt{n})^2+2} < \dfrac{\sqrt{n}} {(\sqrt{n})^2}= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$

The limit is?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the simplest standard ways are,

- $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt n+\frac{2}{\sqrt n}}=0.$$

Also, since denominator goes to infinity, we are allowed to subtract $2.$

- $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt n}=0.$$